# Elemental access in arrays

Tags: c#, .net

I was reading up on data structures from Code Complete. This is when I stumbled through this piece about arrays:

> **Think of arrays as sequential structures** Some of the brightest people in computer science have suggested that arrays never be
>   accessed randomly, but only sequentially (Mills and Linger 1986).
>   Their argument is that random accesses in arrays are similar to random
>   gotos in a program: Such accesses tend to be undisciplined, error
>   prone, and hard to prove correct. Instead of arrays, they suggest
>   using sets, stacks, and queues, whose elements are accessed
>   sequentially.

Does this hold true for `System.Array` class in C#?

Comment: Do you think it holds true? Can you think of a legitimate reason to randomly access arrays?

Comment: Are we looking for use cases for array random access because it makes our program run _faster_ or use cases when it is more logical? There are plenty of cases when accessing array randomally is faster (for example, when implementing a binary tree using an array). However, In C# I haven't found myself using an array for logic. I use IEnumerables and Lists a lot more.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Assuming that by lists you mean `List<T>`, that's an just array.

Comment: @delnan no it's not, it's a list. I don't care how it was implemented in the background. I think of it as a list of things and not a location in memory with pointer offsets etc. It's how I _think_ of the data structure and not how it actually works.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It provides random access. If you think of it as a sequential structure, as the quote in the question demands, that's fine, but that doesn't make them a priori exempt from the question of whether to use their random access capability. NB I also don't think of a plain array in terms of physical memory or pointers; I think of it as a sequence that provides O(1) random access and (in its basic form) no resizing.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that being able to prove correctness is only a concern in specific contexts: e.g. for academic purposes, or for safety-critical systems. For most applications, code clarity is much more important and you won't even attempt to prove correctness. Even `goto`s can have their uses in making code clearer!

Comment: @delnan that's an interesting point. I'm not sure what natural structure in life does that (no re-sizing and random access) I guess that's why I rarely use arrays for anything that is not performance critical.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum A data structure need not be modeled after anything in real life. It only need support the operations my algorithms need efficiently. And there are countless useful algorithms on array-ish data structures, and countless data structures (again with many applications) that can be built atop of arrays. Are you telling me you *never* use the random access capability? (Note that the resizing restriction is only theoretic; it's trivial to build a dynamic array that supports O(1) appending atop of a static array. This makes it quite efficient for stacks and many other use cases.)

Comment: @delnan not at all :) I'm telling you that I _rarely_ use arrays. There are plenty of other data structures with O(1) random access that abstract that from me (like Dictionaries). In C# I don't see what basic arrays give me most of the time. It's very rare that I think of my data as an 'array'. Also, like I said, I think arrays are great for some use cases because they are fast, also they're handy for implementing other data structures.

Comment: @Bernard, I appreciate you asking me back this question! When I first read that random access is error prone, I felt that *somehow* .Net framework might have overcome this limitation. This is the reason I asked the question. I would appreciate your inputs.

Comment: @delnan, You have mentioned that `List<T>` is also an `Array`. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Baqueta, You sure have a point. By safety critical, what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet I'm mainly talking about things where failure would be life-threatening, so key parts of control systems for nuclear reactors, air traffic control, things like that. Even there, correctness is so hard to prove that they usually also rely on redundancy (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundancy_(engineering)#Voting_logic). I'm not saying you shouldn't try hard to write solid, bug-free code, but *proving* correctness is really another matter entirely.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet `List<T>` consists basically of a `T[]` and a bit of metadata. The `T[]` is almost always larger than necessary for the current amount of elements, which is necessary to allow efficient appending (i.e. more efficient than allocating a new `T[]` and copying all elements on every appending). This is also called a *dynamic over-allocating array*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly does. Arrays in C# are very similar to arrays in other programming languages.

Some differences between dynamically allocated arrays in C and arrays in C#:

- In C#, array always knows its length.
- You can't use pointer arithmetic in C# (unless you use `unsafe`). This means that part of the array can't be represented as (pointer, length), it has be represented as something like (reference, start_index, length).

But none of these differences are relevant to the quote in question.

Also, C# makes it easy to treat array as a sequential structure: it implements `IEnumerable<T>` and can be used in a `foreach` (though neither of these allows you to modify the array). This means you can iterate though the array without using indexes. For example:

```
foreach (var item in array)
    Console.WriteLines(array);
```

Or (using LINQ, which is based on `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
var unavailableProducts = products.Where(p => p.InStock == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks,svick, your answer is closest to what I was looking for. Especially for pointing out how the array in C# is different from C. Can you please elaborate on how implementing `IEnumerable<T>` makes it easier to treat the array as sequential? I did not understand the treating as sequential part...

Comment: @TheSilverBullet Examples added.

Comment: But, under the hood, the access continues to be random right? I would presume that the compiler breaks `for` loop and `foreach` loop to the same set of instructions. Am I correct? The difference is that here, the user cannot specify wrong or out-of-bounds index.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet Yeah, the important part here is your code, not the implementation.

Comment: I was specifically asking in the context of the quotation above. Do you think McConnell meant code or the implementation?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet I'm quite sure he was talking about your code. It's similar with gotos: it doesn't matter that the compiled assembly code (or the intermediary IL code) uses them. What matters is that the code you write doesn't contain them.

Comment: Brilliant! Then, the case is closed... Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The point is language-unspecific, so as far as it holds, it holds for C#. (The only exception would be if your language has arrays where random access is not O(1), but I can't think of one off-hand.)

But of course there are situations in programing where you definitely *don't* need to access all items in a collection, but only one particular item per request, and in such situations it can be useful to arrange the items in an array for fast access. I don't think anyone would argue that random access *per se* is undisciplined and should be avoided in any situation - but in those where looping does the trick, it is indeed easier to program and to verify.

Comment: If it doesn't have random access, it's not an array. Unless you're making up terms and ignoring standard CS definitions that are older than most people working in the field.